# Retrieve value from command output

Tags: shell, powershell

I'm looking for a method which would allow me to retrieve a value from a command output. An example might be retrieving the IP address from an `ipconfig` output, or the encryption status from a `manage-bde -status` output. It's essentially the value after the colon **":"**. I tried playing with the findstr options, but I could not retrieve "just" the value. In the ipconfig example, I want only the IP address, and in the "manage-bde" example, I want only the word "protection off". The above two commands are only examples.

In addition, I need to figure out a method to perform a `foreach` in the event there are more than one IP/Nic, or more than one volume.

I could be either just one command, or output the results to a file, and then run something against the file.

Comment: The answer to the basic question here is assign it to a variable. However you are looking to parse from that output. Without a _specific_ example you are just going to get the answer of regex.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a quick example of something you might be able to do for the `ipconfig` example.

Essentially I am retrieving all of the IP Configurations for my local machine, then if their is greater than 1 it will loop through each of these and create an object that's more readable.

```
#Get IP Configurations
$ipList = Get-NetIPConfiguration

#If there is more than 1 item in the ipList
If($ipList.count -gt 1){

    #Loop through each of the IPs int the list
    foreach($entry in $ipList){

        #Create a Custom PowerShell Object and Assign empty attributes for the Name and IP
        $object = new-object psobject | select-object Name, IPAddress

        #Add a value to the $object.Name property
        $object.Name = $entry.InterfaceAlias

        #Add a value to the $object.IPAddress property
        $object.IPAddress = $entry | select -ExpandProperty IPv4Address

        #Store the value of each object in an array
        [array]$output += $object
    }
}

#Output the contents of the Array into a file
$output | export-csv c:\temp\IP_Info.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Now there is more you could do to this, It currently outputs `System.Object` if there is no IP Value found, it also only looks for an IPv4Address

Hopefully this helps you start to find a solution

Comment: A way shorter select with calculated properties to do the (unneccessary) rename `Get-NetIPConfiguration|select @{n='Name';e={$_.Interfacealias}},@{n='IPAddress';e={$_.IPv4Address}}` yields the same.

Comment: @LotPings lots of super short ways to do it, usually I am very verbose on these responses so that the people who ask the question get a better understanding :)